# Data area access through SQL

Tags: db2-400

I am looking for advice on how to use the QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO in a particular situation. So I have created a few views which selects data from multiple tables. I am trying to fetch data from a data area as well using the DATA_AREA_INFO function.

The views need to be installed in a number of data libraries. The create view SQL statement does not have any libraries hardcoded. The tables to pull data from will be based on the default library we set in iSeries navigator while creating the views. So once the view is created, it would permanently point to tables from the default data library set. (Hope this is correct?)

The issue is with fetching the data from the data area:

```
SELECT DATA_AREA_VALUE
FROM TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO(
DATA_AREA_NAME => 'TESTDA1',
DATA_AREA_LIBRARY => '*LIBL'))
```

Writing the statement as above would result in the view selecting the data from the data area present in the library list.

But the jobs from which the views will be executed might not have a library list setup. Hence I cant rely on DATA_AREA_LIBRARY => '*LIBL'

Is there a way I can make the view point to the same data library always (same as how the tables work)?

Comment: If the data area is in the same library as a table of which you know the name, then you can replace *LIBL with `TABLE_SCHEMA('TABLE_IN_THE_SAME_LIBRARY_AS_THE_DATA_AREA')`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap up the data area access in a (service)program which accesses the *dtaara via ILE. The advantage is, that your able to reuse the program in several ways, in and outside an sql context. You can find information about this technique here:

[Scott Klement Powerpoint](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiMvJXY3P_uAhUEKuwKHUlvBBgQFjABegQIARAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scottklement.com%2Fpresentations%2FRPG%2520User%2520Defined%2520Functions%2520%2526%2520Table%2520Functions.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2iyGhWhYsONqoYHxmUvel5)